# how to obfuscate react component or jsx file

Tags: reactjs, security, npm, next.js, obfuscation

i have to share a github repository with others but don't wanna expose my react component

i want to obfuscate a jsx files containing react functional component, styled-components, axios...

nonetheless, still "npm start" or "npm run dev" works in react/next.js

how should i do? is there a solution for this?

or can it be a solution to transform jsx file into obfuscated node moudle?

"how to obfuscate" i searched are focused on build time, full project.

i want it to work for dev time, partially

Comment: What's the use case? Usually, front end code is not interesting enough to steal so this is often a waste of effort. You probably already know this but even obfuscated code can be reverse engineered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obfuscating it within the project will be a nightmare.

My suggestion would be to simply extract the component out into a separate library, build it, publish it, and then add it in your shared project as a dependency.

Then it will only exist as a compiled react component in the node_modules folder.

Comment: thanks for answering. Can the created react component module be obfuscated? For obfuscating library, what tool or library do i have to use?